# Find the coefficients($x^{15}$,$x^{11}$) of the function $(2x^2-\frac{3}{x})^{10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I want to find the coefficients ($x^{15}$,$x^{11}$) of the function $(2x^2-\frac{3}{x})^{10}$
I would like to get some advice how to continue
thanks!

Comment: Start with expanding $(2x^2 - 3/x)^{10}$ using the binomial theorem.

Comment: binomial theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), the $r$th term $$=\binom{10}r(2x^2)^{10-r}\left(-\frac3x\right)^r=\binom{10}r2^{10-r}(-3)^r\cdot x^{2(10-r)-r}=\binom{10}r2^{10-r}(-3)^rx^{20-3r}$$ where integer $r$ lies $\in[0,10]$

For $x^{15},$ we need $20-3r=15\implies r=\frac53$ which is impossible as $r$ is an integer

I leave the case $x^{11}$ for you to complete

Comment: If that's what you call a hint, what do you call a complete answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry while adding the rest I missed to remove 'HINT'

Comment: OP labeled it "homework", and asked for "advice how to continue". OP will not now have the pleasure of working out the solution.

Comment: Sorry , I dont understand it, this is the only way to do that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I thought the first example is required as is corroborated by Ofir Attia's comment

Comment: No, Ofir, it's not the only way to do it --- you could sit down and multiply out $$(2x^2-(3/x))\times(2x^2-(3/x))\times\cdots\times(2x^2-(3/x))$$ but I wouldn't recommend it. Why, did you have some other method in mind? Have you not seen the binomial theorem?

Comment: I saw it, I will try to write again what you answered.

Comment: @OfirAttia, here the $r$th term of $(a+b)^n$ is $\binom nra^{n-r}b^r$ where $0\le r\le n$ and $r$ is an integer

Comment: yes I see it now here : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/BinomialSeries.aspx

Comment: @OfirAttia, as $\frac1x=x^{-1}, (x^2)^{10-r}\cdot\frac1{x^r}=x^{20-2r-r}$

Comment: ok so I just insert the $r$ I get, and the answer is the expression with out the $x\dots$ for example $x^{11}$ is $\binom {10}{3}2^{7}(-3)^3$?